# Get coordinates of a small screen shot location within a large screen shot

Tags: java, location, screenshot, image, coordinate

For example, I am taking a screen shot of a very small portion of the desktop (pretend the coordinates cannot be saved when screen shot taken).  Next, a screen shot of full screen is taken. How do I find the location of the small screen shot within the big screen shot?

Is this even possible in Java?

```
public void RobotScreenCoordinateFinder()
{
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
}
```

Comment: Look how string search works e.g Knuth-Morris-Pratt and Boyer-Moore Algo, and extend it two 2 -dimensions.

Comment: Check ***[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching)*** page

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to use this:

```
BufferedImage screen=robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));c
BufferedImage capture=robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);//assuming that screenRect is your capture
boolean screenMatches=false;
int screenX=0;
int screenY=0;
for(int i=0;i<screen.getWidth()-capture.getWidth();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<screen.getHeight()-capture.getHeight();j++)
    {
        boolean matches=true;
        for(int x=0;x<capture.getWidth();x++)
        {
            for(int y=0;y<capture.getHeight();y++)
            {
                if(screen.getRGB(i+x,j+y)!=capture.getRGB(x,y))
                {
                    matches=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!matches)break;
         }
         if(matches)
         {
             screenMatches=true;
             screenX=i;
             screenY=j;
             break;
         }
    }
    if(screenMatches)break;
}
//now if the capture is in the screen, screenMatches is true and the coordinate of the left up corner is stored in screenX and screenY
if(screenMatches)
{
    System.out.println("Found match with coordinates "+screenX+","+screenY);
}
```